# Can you check if multiple values are the same on the same line in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically, I am trying to check if 6 of my values are the same.  I tried stringing them:

```
if val1 == val2 == val3 == val4 == val5 == val6
  #...
end
```

But this errors out.  Is this possible using another method?
Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
if [val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6].uniq.count == 1
  #...
end
```

If you wanna get fancy, you can try this

```
unless [val2, val3, val4, val5, val6].find{ |x| x != val1 }
  # ...
end
```

The above will stop as soon as it finds an element that is not equal to `val1`, otherwise, the block will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

A cute way:

```
[val1,val2,val3,valN].uniq.size == 1
```

A more prosaic way:

```
[val2,val3,valN].all?{ |x| x == val1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If values are by any chance Fixnum, this sexy line would work:

```
if val1 == val2 & val3 & val4 & val5 & val6
  # ...
end
```

if not, then this fatty would work for any type

```
if [val1] == [val2] & [val3] & [val4] & [val5] & [val6]
   # ...
end
```

Comment: Make a favour to your future you and your fellow developers and don't use this construction.